# Sending an mcrypt-encrypted string via a URL parameter - decoded text is mangled

Tags: php, ajax, get, mcrypt

I'm messing with a simple authorization scheme. I think the easiest way to do it without SSL or other HTTP auth would be a shared key encryption. Adapting a simple example from the PHP manual, I came up with the following:

```
$text = "boggles the invisible monkey will rule the world";
$key = "This is a very secret key";

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

$enc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

$iv = base64_encode($iv);
$enc = base64_encode($enc);

echo '<a href="temp2.php?iv='.$iv.'&text='.$enc.'">link</a><br />';
```

The page that receives this request (temp2.php) looks like this:

```
$key = "This is a very secret key";

$iv = base64_decode($_GET["iv"]);
$enc = base64_decode($_GET["text"]);

$crypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $enc, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

echo "$crypttext<br>";
```

This gets very close, but it doesn't decode properly-- it echoes

`boggles the invisible monkey will rule t—;eôügJë`

I'm not sure what the hangup is, I tried urlencode/urldecode and htmlentities, thinking maybe a character was mangled in the request, but no difference.

Is there something else I'm missing? Perhaps padding?

Thanks

Comment: Base64 strings frequently end in the `=` char.  I bet you'r losing one during URL parsing (since = is something of a special char).  Try `urlencode(base64_encode())`?

Comment: Plus, you should be posting this data, since there are limits to the size of the get string (it's up there in modern servers, but they do exist)

Comment: @Frank Farmer-- I've tried the urlencode/decode route. Didn't help. @ircmaxwell-- you're right, but this is a pretty small string initially.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It happens that your encrypted text will end up looking something like:

```
Z5DlBqT8yEB4HKLkAlvfJoWaHgnNVLFh7jls6L85sLriedc82uFQxm+M62I41oB7
```

See that plus sign there?  Plus signs in URLs get turned into spaces.

When manually converting that plus sign to a space and decrypting the result, the output is the corrupted junk that you've witnessed.

You should run both the IV and the encrypted text through [`rawurlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) (*not* `urlencode`) before sticking it into the link.  This will properly encode the plus sign, which will preserve it through the process.  You don't need to (and should not) `urldecode` the string on the other side -- PHP will have done this for you.

Comment: @Frank, it happens that PHP's implementation of base64 decode ignores missing or extra equal signs at the end.  Other implementations may not be so liberal, so that could indeed be a problem in other circumstances.