# Using mcrypted values in URL

Tags: php, urlencode, mcrypt

I wrote a little class to send private data with the url (can't use cookies/sessions or anything else for it). I encrypt/decrypt it with PHP's mcrypt and also base64-en/decoded it for use in the url.

Unfortunately I still end up with wrong results from time to time. I noticed that this always happens when at least a `+` appears in the url. I also played around with `rawurlencode` and `urlencode`/ `urldecode`, without success. I also tried `strtr()` the encrypted data, but somehow the `+` still appear. Anyone got an idea ?

Here's my class:

```
class crypto 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $this->llave = 'da332sdf9'; 
    }

    public function make_crypt($string)
    {   
        $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $this->llave, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv);
        $crypt = rawurlencode(base64_encode($crypt));
        $crypt = strtr($crypt, '+/', '-_');     
        return $crypt;
    }

    public function get_crypt($data)
    {   
        $crypt = strtr($crypt, '-_', '+/');     
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $this->llave, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv);
        return $decrypted;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should run both the IV and the encrypted text through rawurlencode (not urlencode) before sticking it into the link. Maybe look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5758002/461212)

Comment: A little sidenote, since you are using ECB mode then you can ignore IV entirely. It is not used in ECB mode. IV is only used in CBC mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean you tried URL encoding 'without success'? URL encoding the value does work, otherwise the function would be broken. I use it in my framework and have no errors.

Are you sure you are encoding the crypted value? Don't encode the entire URL.

Comment: I'm only encoding the encrypted value. Somehow the `+` won't disappear :(

Comment: Can you show code that builds your URL? Because bug must be there. rawurlencode() does encode + sign.

Comment: AAAARRRRRGH! While wanting to post the code that builds my URL, I saw that I put a wrong `urldecode()` in front of it in my rage of fixing. Later I only sat in front of the crypto class and ignored that. Now it logically works. Thanks for that little hint ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Observations

`$crypt = strtr($crypt, '-_', '+/');` ?? where is `crypt` defined ???

`rawurlencode` where is the decoding ....

I always prefer to `HEX` so that i don't have to worry about `url` safe characters

### Sample Test your current class would Fail

```
$crypt = new Crypto ();
echo "<pre>";
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    $pass = generatePassword ( mt_rand ( 5, 10 ) );
    $test = $crypt->make_crypt ( $pass );
    $output = $crypt->get_crypt ( $test );

    if ($pass == $output) {
        echo " $pass ($test) = $output \n";
    } else {
        var_dump ( $pass, $output );
        echo " $pass ($test) != $output \n";
    }
}
```

### Solution

```
class Crypto {

    private $iv_size;
    private $iv;
    private $llave;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size ( MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB );
        $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv ( $this->iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND );
        $this->llave = 'da332sdf9';
    }

    public function make_crypt($string) {
        $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt ( MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $this->llave, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv );
        return bin2hex ( $crypt );
    }

    public function get_crypt($data) {
        $data = pack ( "H*", $data );
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt ( MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $this->llave, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->iv );
        return trim ( $decrypted );
    }
}
```

### Solution Output

```
 tXHhC8fk4 (b929695d39555523348051a72d15baaf) = tXHhC8fk4 
 drKH9 (909994926fe5cd30) = drKH9 
 mNwh6K (10af1bb381338943) = mNwh6K 
 CJZvqwGX (aa705c290759b18d) = CJZvqwGX 
 Jt4W7j (bc7ee842041b9860) = Jt4W7j 
 tgCHXyPvm (9f46b74ef59ee70da1dda30b3e52fe92) = tgCHXyPvm 
 LYxhVj (9e2079cff9d54007) = LYxhVj 
 kR8WLwh3T (3e4606d65defc74f3c82af5fb095f41d) = kR8WLwh3T 
 Z8NqWM6RHj (1d9eea2358674d78cc43e024cba5ba48) = Z8NqWM6RHj 
 TtqRf7M (09ef38114bb729c4) = TtqRf7M
```

**Function Used to generate Data**

```
function generatePassword($length = 8) {
    $password = "";
    $possible = "2346789bcdfghjkmnpqrtvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRTVWXYZ";
    $maxlength = strlen ( $possible );
    if ($length > $maxlength) {
        $length = $maxlength;
    }
    $i = 0;
    while ( $i < $length ) {
        $char = substr ( $possible, mt_rand ( 0, $maxlength - 1 ), 1 );
        if (! strstr ( $password, $char )) {
            $password .= $char;
            $i ++;
        }

    }
    return $password;

}
```